# Degrees of freedom in a $n \times n$ table

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have an $n \times n$ table where each row and each column sums to some number $k$. Say that the elements of the table and $k$ are real numbers. Now the question is how many places can we fill in the table in any way such that the remaining places can be filled in a way such that the sums are correct. This is what we call the degree of freedom. The top left $(n - 1) \times (n - 1)$ subrectangle can be filled out in any way and we can always extend it to a good solution so the degree of freedom is at least $(n - 1)^2$. Also there must be an element missing from each row and each column. So the degree of freedom is at most $n^2 - n$. I've read that the degree of freedom is $(n - 1)^2$ but there was no proof supported and this is how far I've got. Could someone give me a hint on this?

Comment: it's not clear what you mean by "sums are correct".

Comment: You have answered your own question. If you fill in the top left $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ in any way, then the remaining entries are uniquely determined.

Comment: @svsring by sums are correct I mean that if I fill in the table at various places I can still fill the remaining places in at least one way such that each row and column sum adds up to k

Comment: @almagest I think the OP's question is whether more than $(n-1)^2$ squares can be filled.

Comment: @shardulc They can't because the remaining squares are *uniquely* determined by the row and column sums.

Comment: @almagest Yes but that doesn't prove that I can't fill out any other subset of the table which is good and has more than $(n - 1)^2$ elements

Comment: @jakab922 A possible hint is that every row and every column must have a unique free space, not shared as some other row/column's free space. (If it is shared, then there is a way to assign the elements such that the 'free space' must take on two different values.) But $n^2 - 2n = (n-1)^2 - 1$, so there must be one space which I'm overlooking.

Comment: @shardulc What do you mean by free space?

Answer (score 1):

So I have a solution using linear algebra. We need to solve the following linear equations(row sums):

$$\forall i \in 1\dots n \sum_{j = 1}^{n}x_{i,j} = k$$

and(column sums)

$$\forall j \in 1 \dots n \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i, j} = k$$

If we want to prove the claim we have to prove that the matrix here has rank $2n - 1$. It's easy to see that the first $n$ equations are independent. Same goes for the second $n$ equations. The following is also true:

$$\sum_{i=2}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{i, j} - \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i,j} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{1,j}$$

Basically this means that the first row sum equals the next $n - 1$ row sums minus the column sums. For clarification the matrix for $n = 3$ looks like this(when the variables are in row continuous order):

$$\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix} $$

And I guess it's easy to see that the rest of the $2n - 1$ rows are independent since the last $n$ rows have a unique element in the first $n$ columns of the matrix and the rows $2$ to $n$ are all zeroes in these columns.

Comment: Could someone confirm that the proof above is correct?

Comment: As almagest pointed out in a comment under the question, you don't need this, since you already know that $(n-1)^2$ numbers can be freely chosen and then determine the entire table. That couldn't be if this matrix didn't have rank $2n-1$.

Comment: @joriki It is needed because you need to show that you can't  have more than $(n - 1)^2$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: With extending the linear algebraic argument one can show that the degree of freedom for the $d$ dimensional version of the problem is $(n - 1)^d$

Comment: Regarding your previous comment: The fact that $(n-1)^2$ elements can be freely chosen and determine the others is enough to show that this is the number of degree freedoms; it is then impossible for the same property to hold for some other number of entries.

Comment: @joriki Look, finding a solution with a given value doesn't imply it's the maximal value hence the above proof. No further discussion is needed I guess.

Comment: Not sure why you go to a site like this if you're so sure you know better than others. I would have been happy to explain if you'd been interested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40342/discussion-between-jakab922-and-joriki).